# iPhone Storyboard, programmatically calling segues, navigation issues

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, segue

So I have an iPhone app. It has a simple structure, all based on a `UINavigationController`.

I have a storyboard that has one view, a segue to another view, etc. Now this other view has a `UITextView` that I do not want to edit on this screen - if the user taps this, I want it instead to fly over to a second screen which basically has the same text view, but this one is full-screen, and the user will edit the text on that screen before returning to the previous screen.

So I capture the `textViewShouldBeginEditing` method. I previously, in the storyboard editor, manually created a push segue from the previous view controller to this new view controller, and named it so that I can call it by it's identity, which I do with:

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    // This is called when the user clicks into the textView as if to edit it.

    // Instead of editing it, go to this other view here:
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"editMemoSegue" sender:self];

    // Return NO, as I don't actually want to edit the text on this screen:
    return NO;
}
```

Seems reasonable. And it works. Sorta. It does in fact shoot me over to that other view. That other view's events fire up, I set it's text view to become first responder, I edit the text on that screen. Everyone's happy.

Until I  want to use the back button to return to the previous view.

Then I quickly find out - my navigation stack is foobared. Most of the time, I have, for some reason, TWO instances of my new editing controller on the stack, so the first time I hit the back button I get the same stuff over again. Then, oddly, occasionally, it will work as intended, and I will see my previous controller with only one back click.

I started reading the log, and I found this:

```
2012-12-09 09:41:03.463 APP[8368:c07] nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
2012-12-09 09:41:03.818 APP[8368:c07] Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
2012-12-09 09:41:03.819 APP[8368:c07] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <SecondController: 0x83881d0>.
```

So obviously, I'm doing something incorrectly here. The question is, what? And how do I do what I want in the way that correctly appeases the tiki gods of the iPhone framework?

Comment: That error message, "nested push animation" usually results from multiple pushes to the same controller. Is the above code, the only place where you perform that segue? Do you just have the navigation controller and the 2 above mentioned controllers in your storyboard?

Comment: That code is the only place where that segue is called. That controller is the second controller in the nav stack (A > B > C, this is happening on B > C).

Comment: Something must be set up wrong somewhere. The code you posted should work fine. If you can post your project somewhere I can look at it, but there's not much else to say without seeing the project.

Comment: Try putting a log in the textViewShouldBeginEditing method to see if it's called twice. It seems to me that these kinds of delegate methods sometimes are.

Comment: And so it is!!! textViewShouldBeginEditing is getting called twice! I don't have a clue in the world why, but sure enough, there it is. A simple flag variable to determine if the method had already been called prevents this, and everything works like a charm. I cannot accept this as an answer, but should you post this as an answer, I will certainly do so - as this is the solution to the problem.

Comment: @mschultz: just a side note, I think you should probably present **modally** the view controller where you edit your UITextView. I think it's the kind of situation where it's appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to see if the textViewShouldBeginEditing is being called twice. I've noticed that these kinds of delegate calls sometimes are.

Comment: And so it is!!! textViewShouldBeginEditing is getting called twice! I don't have a clue in the world why, but sure enough, there it is. A simple flag variable to determine if the method had already been called prevents this, and everything works like a charm. I cannot accept this as an answer, but should you post this as an answer, I will certainly do so - as this is the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

How is your @"editMemoSegue" being created on the storyboard? is it created from the textView? if it is then you should recreate it directly from the view controller or from the top status bar on the view controller that way it wont be called twice when you touch the trigger object and when you call it programmatically.

Comment: I just verified this - the segue is in fact created from the first view controller and is pointed directly at the second view controller. I expected this to be the correct pattern for this?